# Screen Sharing with Multiple Monitors

Tags: screen-sharing

I'm connecting to a work VPN through cisco anyconnect and remoting into my work computer via Mac's native Screen Sharing.

My work computer (iMac 2019) AND home computer (macbook pro 2014) both have dual monitors but I seem to only be able to view the remote desktop on 1 (either just the primary screen or BOTH work screens on the 1 home screen).

Question:  Is it possible to screen share a dual monitor setup on 2 monitors?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only work around I found was to duplicate the Screen Sharing application. Connect to your work computer with the first application, once connected launch the second (duplicated) application and it will give you a second window. You can then allocate one screen to each application window.